# How to write a bash script, that logs onto an other machine to do stuff?

Tags: bash, ssh, shell-script

Is it possible to write a bash script, that

1. would be started from machine A, logs in on a different machine B by ssh (both machines A and B would be Linux-Machines),
2. copys some files on to machine B
3. runs a python script a given python script on these machines.
4. transfers the results back to machine A
5. logs off from machine B.

Is this technically doable?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Of course it is doable:

```
scp file user@host:
ssh user@host path_to_script
scp user@host:file_to_copy ./
```

and that's it...

But there is one problem: you will be asked for password three times. To avoid that you could generate ssh keys and authorize users by these keys.

To generate ssh keys run `ssh-keygen -t rsa`, answer questions and copy public key to remote host (machine B) to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file. Private key should be saved in `~/.ssh/id_rsa` on local machine (A).

Comment: If public keys arent an option, you could do something crude to minimize password prompts like `cat file | ssh user@host 'cat > /destination/of/file; /path/to/script &>/dev/null; cat results' > /destination/of/results`

Comment: If you do want to use the password, you could always use OpenSSH's connection pooling by defining `ControlMaster=yes` and `ControlPath=/path/to/socketfile`, and then start one ssh connection with `-f` to run a background ssh.  Tell all subsequent SSH connections to use the same socket file.

Answer (score 5):

I is possible to do everything in a single `ssh` connection/session:

```
ssh user@host "cat > remote_dst; command; cat remote_src" < local_src > local_dst
```

This:

1. Copies `local_src` to `remote_dst`,
2. Executes `command`,
3. Copies `remote_src` to `local_dst`.

But if `command` writes on `stdout`, the result with also be in `local_dst`.  If `command` reads input from `stdin`, it will receive and `EOF`.

Answer (score 3):

While you can do this inside a single ssh session, it's a bit tricky to combine copying files with running commands.

The easiest way to tackle this task is to run separate SSH sessions for the three operations:

```
rsync -a inputs/ machineB:inputs/
ssh machineB 'some command -i inputs -o outputs'
rsync -a machineB:outputs/ outputs/
```

This requires authenticating to machineB three times. The recommended way to avoid authenticating multiple times is to use the connection sharing facility in modern versions of OpenSSH: start a master connection to B once and for all, and let SSH automatically piggyback onto that master connection. [Add `ControlMaster auto` and a `ControlPath` line to your `~/.ssh/config`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33557/using-an-already-established-ssh-channel/33581#33581), then start a master connection in the background, then perform your tasks.

```
ssh -fN machineB                         # start a master connection in the background
# Subsequent connections will be slaves to the existing master connection
rsync -a inputs/ machineB:inputs/
ssh machineB 'some command -i inputs -o outputs'
rsync -a machineB:outputs/ outputs/
```

Rather than use scp or rsync to copy files, it may be easier to mount the remote filesystem under [SSHFS](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html). This will take care of setting up a master connection, by the way (assuming you've set up your `~/.ssh/config` as indicated above).

```
mkdir /net/machineB
sshfs machineB: /net/machineB
cp -Rp inputs /net/machineB/
ssh machibeB 'some command -i inputs -o outputs'
cp -Rp /net/machineB/outputs .
```