# Reusing ssh session for repeated rsync commands

Tags: ssh, rsync

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using an already established SSH channel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33557/using-an-already-established-ssh-channel)

I have a remote server accessible via a chain of SSH proxies. The resulting channel is wide and fast enough, but setting it up takes a couple seconds.

I want to periodically run `rsync` against this server, synchronizing small changes to a relatively large file tree.

When I do it plainly by `rsync -r source_dir remote_host:target_dir`, most of the time is spent establishing the connection. For comparison, establishing an interactive connection to that host takes about the same time.

*Is there a way to somehow reuse the SSH connection across several `rsync` invocations, to avoid the connection delay?*

The catch is that I don't want *continuous* replication of files to the remote host; file tree has to be consistent at the moment of the replication, so I'd like to trigger the rsync event myself.

I'm open to using something else, e.g. `git`, as long as I avoid the constant reconnection delay and don't have to open a listening port on the remote host.

Comment: Won't running an ssh tunnel in the background do what you want?

Comment: @terdon: probably it would. I'd appreciate if you composed an answer showing how to use rsync with that.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Yes, see the `ControlMaster` and `ControlPath` options.

You can start the master connection with:

```
mkdir ~/.ssh/ctl
ssh -nNf -o ControlMaster=yes -o ControlPath="$HOME/.ssh/ctl/%L-%r@%h:%p" user@host
```

And then use rsync with:

```
rsync -e "ssh -o 'ControlPath=$HOME/.ssh/ctl/%L-%r@%h:%p'" ...
```

Then

```
ssh -O exit -o ControlPath="$HOME/.ssh/ctl/%L-%r@%h:%p" user@host
```

to terminate the master connection.

(And by the way, some versions of ubuntu have an annoying *feature* in that they rebuild `/etc/motd` upon every login (including non-interactive ssh sessions), which can take a long time if part of that involves checking if updates are available for instance. IIRC, you can disable it by removing `pam_motd` from your pam configuration)

Comment: It should be noted that OpenSSH client also supports the `-M` command-line option whith the same meaning as `-o ControlMaster=yes` and the `-S <path>` command-line option with the same meaning as `-o ControlPath=<path>`. At least this is the case with OpenSSH 5.1p1.

Comment: Just to add that you can use `ControlPersist` to timeout the connection so that there is no need to exit.

Comment: There's no `ControlPersist` in older versions of `ssh` but running sleep on the remote host does something similar: e.g. `ssh -f -M -S <path> user@host sleep 60` (Except `ControlPersist` counts idle seconds while this counts from the initial connection.)