# 'rsync' batch mode

Tags: ssh, rsync

Rsync has a flag for specifying remote shell to use thru `-e` flag. Common usage like so,

```
rsync -e "ssh ..." [source] [destination]
```

I'm wondering if there is a way for it to reuse an already running remote shell?

Like

1. Start ssh and connect to server while remembering the pid
2. Successive calls to `rsync -e [pid] [source] [destination]`
3. Terminate ssh

EDIT: I'm using cygwin. I tried ControlMaster but can't get it to work. I suspect it is not possible thru CygWin [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20959792/is-ssh-controlmaster-with-cygwin-on-windows-actually-possible)

Comment: Check this post : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50508/reusing-ssh-session-for-repeated-rsync-commands

Comment: @ankit7540 Thank you for that info. I tried using ControlMaster but can't get it to work. I'm using CygWin. I edited my post to include this information.