# Select a range of logs from daily log archives

Tags: bash, logs, wildcards

I have a folder containing daily logs, named as :

```
system-2013-01-01.log
system-2013-01-02.log
system-2013-01-03.log
system-2013-01-04.log
system-2013-01-05.log
system-2013-01-06.log
system-2013-01-07.log
system-2013-01-08.log
...
system-2013-01-31.log
```

How can I select ( and copy ) the logs from 2013-01-01 to 2013-01-15 ?

Comment: What shell are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu's default bash shell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bash` supports [brace expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html), which allows you to specify multiple values, or even ranges, to be expanded in a command. For example,

```
$ echo {1..5}
1 2 3 4 5
$ echo foo_{01..05}
foo_01 foo_02 foo_03 foo_04 foo_05
```

So you can easy specify the range of files to copy as

```
cp system-2013-01-{01..31}.log /some/destination/dir
```

which `bash` will expand to

```
cp system-2013-01-01.log system-2013-01-02.log system-2013-01-03.log ...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a file for every day, you can use a sequence expression in [braces](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion):

```
cp -p system-2013-01-{01..15}.log /elsewhere
```

If you don't have a file for every day, you can use character [patterns](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching).

```
cp -p system-2013-01-0[1-9].log system-2013-01-1[0-5].log /elsewhere
```

If there is no matching file in one of the two ranges, the pattern will be left unexpanded. Set the [nullglob](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Shopt-Builtin) option (bash-specific) to avoid this (`shopt nullglob`).

Zsh makes this easier thanks to its `<start-stop>` numeric range [glob pattern](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Operators).

```
cp -p system-2013-01-<1-15>.log /elsewhere
```

A different approach that doesn't require zsh and scales well to more complex cases is to use `find` to generate the list of files. You don't need to worry about non-matches: `cp` will be executed for each match.

```
find . \( -name 'system-2013-01-0[1-9].log' -o -name 'system-2013-01-1[0-5].log' \) -exec cp -p {} /elsewhere \;
```

Add `-type d -prune -o` after `find .` to avoid recursing into subdirectories.

Comment: a side question: when using braces with `scp`, the command will ask for password for every file being transferred. Is there any flags that can avoid asking password for multiple times?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor See [Using an already established SSH channel](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33557/using-an-already-established-ssh-channel).