# rsync'ing multiple {src,dest} pairs

Tags: ssh, rsync

I have a remote server on which I am deploying code. I am currently using `scp` to upload code, but `scp` is very slow and I'd like to switch to `rsync` (or something else which is more efficient). The bottleneck is in making the `ssh` connection, so I'd like to minimize the number of connections I make to the server.

Locally, my build process outputs a directory `out` containing `bin`, `lib` and `etc` subdirectories. I am pushing a subset of the output files to matching positions on the remote server.

My `scp` commands look like this:

```
scp out/bin/$BINFILES remote:/usr/bin
scp out/lib/$LIBFILES remote:/usr/lib
scp out/etc/$ETCFILES remote:/etc
```

This makes three connections to the remote server, and copies the files in full even if they haven't been modified. This is what I did with `rsync`:

```
rsync -e ssh -avz out/bin/$BINFILES remote:/usr/bin
rsync -e ssh -avz out/lib/$LIBFILES remote:/usr/lib
rsync -e ssh -avz out/etc/$ETCFILES remote:/etc
```

which is faster (compression and elimination of duplicates), but still makes three connections to the remote server.

Is there a way to achieve these three copies using a single `rsync` command? I'm open to e.g. putting all {src,dest} pairs in a temporary file before copying, if that will work.

I'm also open to trying a different tool, but it should be available for OS X (my current development platform), and it should preferably support transfer optimizations like `rsync` does.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason multiple successive rsync commands are slow is that establishing an SSH connection takes a little while. You can solve this problem by [using an established SSH channel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33557/using-an-already-established-ssh-channel). [Set up master connection sharing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33557/using-an-already-established-ssh-channel/33581#33581), then open a master connection, use your rsync commands unchanged (note that `-e ssh` has been the default since a decade or so) and finally close the SSH connection:

```
ssh -Nf remote
rsync -avz out/bin/$BINFILES remote:/usr/bin
rsync -avz out/lib/$LIBFILES remote:/usr/lib
rsync -avz out/etc/$ETCFILES remote:/etc
ssh -O exit remote
```

If you can't use SSH connection sharing (e.g. because one side is running Dropbear or a very old version of OpenSSH), you can [establish a tunnel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33557/using-an-already-established-ssh-channel/33573#33573), but this is more cumbersome.

Alternatively, with a bit of work, you may be able to refactor your rsync command into one, by playing with [rsync filters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2161/rsync-filter-copying-one-pattern-only/2503#2503) and symbolic links. If you can move the `bin` and `lib` directories, it's pretty easy:

```
mkdir out/usr
mv out/bin out/lib out/usr/
rsync -avz \
      --include='/bin/***' --include='/lib/***' --include='/etc/***' \
      --exclude='*' out/ remote:/
```

If you can't move them, but there aren't any absolute symbolic links in the trees that you're copying, you can use an absolute symlink and tell rsync to treat it as a directory:

```
ln -s "$PWD" out/usr
rsync -avz --copy-unsafe-links \
      --include='/bin/***' --include='/lib/***' --include='/etc/***' \
      --exclude='*' out/ remote:/
```

Comment: I knew that establishing SSH connections was the bottleneck, but I didn't know about connection sharing...nifty! Thanks a bunch!