# Scp command over ssh without password in script

Tags: shell-script, ssh, scp

Here is my problem:
I would like to perform scp command after ssh to remote server without typing any passwords. I describe my steps.
My first steps were:

> `ssh-keygen -t rsa` and
>
> `local@host$ ssh-copy-id -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub  remote@host` on local machine

Then I did the same on remote machine:

> `ssh-keygen -t rsa` and
>
> `remote@host$ ssh-copy-id -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub  local@host`

After all described above I could do ssh on both machines without typing any password. I could perform scp command on remote machine like `scp /home/remote/info.txt.gz local@host:/root/` and everything worked perfectly.

> Then I tried to make a script with some actions described below and the last step in my script was `scp` command that did not work as I expected.

```
#!/bin/bash
remote_user=$1
remote_host=$2
local_user=$3
local_host=$4

echo "Testing connection to ${host}..."
ssh -n -o NumberOfPasswordPrompts=0 ${remote_user}@${remote_host}
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "FATAL: You don't have passwordless ssh working."
    echo "Try running ssh-keygen"
    exit 1
fi
echo "Okey. Starting the process."
ssh ${remote_user}@${remote_host} netstat -tulpn > /home/${remote_user}/info.txt;uptime |awk '{ print $3 }' >> /home/${remote_user}/info.txt;
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "An error occurred."
else
    echo "File is ready for gzipping!"
fi
gzip /home/${remote_user}/info.txt
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "file was not archived"
else
    echo "Archive is ready!"
fi
echo "Starting copy archive from ${remote_host} to ${local_host}"
scp /home/${remote_user}/info.txt.gz ${local_user}@${local_host}:/root/
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Error while transferring!"
else
    echo "Copy has been transferred successfully!"
fi
```

Scp command asked me for password o_O.

> When I did all steps in script manually everything worked perfectly but in script `scp` demanded password. I read a lot through **stackexchange** and found this answer [Using an already established SSH channel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33557/using-an-already-established-ssh-channel). This answer requires Open SSH but my problem can be resolved manually via SSH as I said but in script it did not work.
>   What am I going to do to make `scp` works without password?

Comment: TL;DR. Is your SSH key encrypted (ex: do you type in a password when using your key?). Are you using `ssh-agent` (or PuTTY Agent on Windows)?

Comment: You know you're executing that `scp` from the first host right, not from `remote_host`  The only command you're execute on the remote host is `netstat -tulpn` everything else is on your first host

Comment: Try adding the `-vv` flag on the `scp` command to see if it's even attempting to do key-based auth.

Comment: Criveti Mihai, yes I am using Putty Agent on Windows.

Comment: First line of your script should be `#!/bin/bash`. Did you do all actions as root - or some as another user? I think your scp line last parameter should be `${remote_user}@${remote_host}:/root/` - assuming you really want to save the .gz file at remote's /root which seems a strange location.

Comment: I did all actions as root - FOR SURE! Such locations I had given only for example - because we can use in spite of them real host names and ip addresses.

Comment: `#!/bin/bash` it is just my blot. Thanks! I have corrected it.

Comment: Your code uses paths such as `/home/${remote_user}/` on the _local machine_ all over the place. Is that really intentional?

Comment: roaima, it is just an example.

Answer (score 1):

If below scp command is being run on `local_host`,then you are trying to scp as `local_user` to `local_host` as `local_user` - ofcourse this would prompt for password, as you had only password less login for remote <-> local users only - not local <-> local

```
scp /home/${remote_user}/info.txt.gz ${local_user}@${local_host}:/root/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have already setup ssh keys, then look into transffering files using sftp. Single command, you don't need to go by the way you are currently trying to do it i.e. ssh then scp, plain sftp would work.

Comment: I tried to use what you said, mtk. Something like this `sftp ${local_user}@${local_host} <<EOT
put info.txt.tgz
quit
EOT` inspite of `scp` command  but it asked for password again

Comment: @fuser some step would be missing. check this post to setup passwordless sftp http://stackoverflow.com/a/15808596/1135954

Comment: Why do I need to set up passwordless sftp If I have already had passwordless ssh?