# How to prompt a password automatically in Unix Shell script?

Tags: shell-script, ssh, password

I have the below line in a script. When I run it, it prompts for a password to copy files in the server. I need the password to be taken from the script.

```
for i in cat forwarders
do scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $filename $tarfile badgeid@$i:/tmp;
done
```

Comment: Have a look at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/246441/scp-command-over-ssh-without-password-in-script

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to check `expect` command. A similar situation (with `ssh`) should look like ...

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
[...]
spawn ssh [lindex $argv 1]@root@[lindex $argv 0]@x.y.z.j -tt
expect "*?assword" {
   send "$PASSWORD\r"
[...]
```