# scp files from multiple directories on local to multiple directories on remote in one command

Tags: scp, file-transfer

I need to copy some files from multiple local directories to multiple remote directories.

The command:

```
scp -v /file/source1/* username@host_server:/file/destination1
scp -v /file/source2/* username@host_server:/file/destination2
scp -v /file/source3/* username@host_server:/file/destination3
```

It asks for password again and again.

The command:

```
scp file1 file2 ... fileN user@host:/destination/directory/
```

Will put all the files into one destination directory.

But my destination are different for all the files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have multiple destinations in one `scp` command. If you want to make a single SSH connection, you'll need to use some other tool.

The simplest solution is to mount the remote filesystem over [SSHFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS) and then use the `cp` command. This requires SFTP access.

```
mkdir host_server
sshfs username@host_server:/file host_server
cp /file/source1/* host_server/destination1
cp /file/source2/* host_server/destination2
cp /file/source3/* host_server/destination3
fusermount -u host_server
rmdir host_server
```

Another solution is to first organize the files locally, then copy the hierarchy. This requires rsync.

```
mkdir destination1 destination2 destination3
ln -s /file/source1/* destination1
ln -s /file/source2/* destination2
ln -s /file/source3/* destination3
rsync -a --copy-unsafe-links destination1 destination2 destination3 username@host_server:/file
rm -r destination1 destination2 destination3
```

Another solution is to keep using `scp`, but first open a master connection to the server. This is explained in [Using an already established SSH channel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33557/using-an-already-established-ssh-channel/33581#33581)

Alternatively, just bear with it and make three `scp` connections. But don't use your password to log in; instead, create a key pair and load the private key into your key agent (`ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`), then you won't have to type anything on each connection.

Answer (score 2):

1. to avoid the repeated password prompts, use key-based authentication rather than password-based.

   e.g. run `ssh-keygen` on your local machine and then run `ssh-copy-id user@remotehost` for each remote host.  That'll be the last time you need to enter the password when you `ssh` or `scp` from that machine.

   Use a good pass-phrase on your key and run `ssh-agent` or similar.  That way you'll only have to enter your private key's pass-phrase the first time you use it in a login session.
2. Use `pdcp` from the `pdsh` package.  For example:

   `pdcp -w host1,host2,host3 /path/to/source/file /path/on/destination/`

   or if your hostnames match a pattern:

   `pdcp -w host[1-3] /path/to/source/file /path/on/destination/`

   You can't have multiple destinations, but you can have multiple sources.  e.g. `pdcp -w h1,h2,h3 file1 file2 file3 /remote-path/` will copy to the /remote-path/ directory on each machine (any target machines where that directory is missing will output an error message)

   You can use a for loop wrapper if you need to copy multiple source files to different directories on multiple hosts.  you could do the same with plain old `scp` but you'd need an outer loop for the hosts as well as an inner loop to do the `scp`s.   Also, `pdcp` copies to multiple machines in parallel, not one at a time.

   With `pdsh` (and `pdcp`) you can configure arbitrary names for groups of machines, e.g. all compute nodes are in the `compute-nodes` group, all web servers in the `web` group, database servers in `db`, all hosts in group `all` etc.

   Then you can do things like:

   `pdsh -g web 'uname -a ; uptime'`
   or
   `pdcp -g web,db /etc/motd /etc/`

Answer (score 1):

**scp** uses **ssh** for data transfer, and uses the same authentication and provides the same security as **ssh**. Unlike **rcp**, **scp** will ask for passwords or passphrases if they are needed for authentication. So you can:
1. Settle **ssh** for connection via public key by editing remote `sshd_config` like

```
# Should we allow Identity (SSH version 1) authentication?
RSAAuthentication yes       
# Should we allow Pubkey (SSH version 2) authentication?
PubkeyAuthentication yes
# Where do we look for authorized public keys?
# If it doesn't start with a slash, then it is
# relative to the user's home directory
AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys
```

Generate key-pairs

```
localhost$ ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

And send it to remote host

```
localhost$ scp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub youruser@remote.server.host
localhost$ ssh youruser@remote.server.host
remote.server.host$ [ -d ~/.ssh ] || (mkdir ~/.ssh; chmod 700 ~/.ssh)
remote.server.host$ cat ~/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
remote.server.host$ chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Or
2. [Unsecure] Set *passwordless* remote host user
Or
3. Use scripts with `expect`

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
stty -echo
send_user -- "Enter Password: "
expect_user -re "(.*)\n"
send_user "\n"
stty echo
set PASS $expect_out(1,string)
…
spawn scp -v /file/source1/* username@host_server:/file/destination1
expect "assword:"
send $PASS"\r"
expect eof
```

Answer (score 0):

With a very slight modification in your command, this can be achieved as shown below.

Assuming you have `source1, source2` .. folders inside your "file" folder, you can run as below to copy all these folders `source1, source2 ..` into the destination server.

```
scp -r /source/file username@host_server:/file/destination1
```

This will create the folders `source1, source2` and copy their contents in the respective folders present in your destination path 
`/file/destination1` on the target server.