# Execute multiple ssh commands with different switch

Tags: ssh, command-line

I have a bash script for copying two files from a remote machine (that I cannot control), stored in a a path that needs `root` access. Here it is:

```
ssh administrator@host "mkdir ${DIR}"
ssh -t administrator@host "sudo su - root -c 'cp /path/for-root-only/data1/${FILENAME} ${DIR}/'"
ssh administrator@host "mv ${DIR}/${FILENAME} ${DIR}/data1-${FILENAME}"
ssh -t administrator@host "sudo su - root -c 'cp /path/for-root-only/data2/${FILENAME} ${DIR}/'"
scp administrator@host:$DIR/{${FILENAME},data1-${FILENAME}} .
ssh administrator@host "rm -r ${DIR}"
```

The script prompt for the same password a lot of time. I tried to merge all commands through here document like this for `ssh -t`:

```
ssh -t administrator@host << EOF
    mkdir ${DIR}
    sudo su - root -c 'cp /path/for-root-only/data1/${FILENAME} ${DIR}/'
    mv ${DIR}/${FILENAME} ${DIR}/data1-${FILENAME}
    sudo su - root -c 'cp /path/for-root-only/data2/${FILENAME} ${DIR}/'
EOF
scp administrator@host:$DIR/{${FILENAME},data1-${FILENAME}} .
ssh administrator@host "rm -r ${DIR}"
```

but there is this warning:

> Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.

I would like to ask if there is a proper way to write that script to minimize the number of password prompting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do it as a *HERE* document (which is what the `<<` stuff does).

You can simply do `ssh remotehost "command1; command2 ; command3"`

e.g.

```
% ssh localhost "date ; uptime ; echo hello"
sweh@localhost's password: 
Tue Jul 19 08:07:48 EDT 2016
 08:07:48 up 15 days, 31 min,  3 users,  load average: 0.33, 0.33, 0.40
hello
```

The `scp` however, won't easily merge that way.

So you may want to look into using *public key authentication* instead of password authentication (also known as "ssh keys").  That's normally how things like this are automated.

Comment: Thanks. do ssh keys need operation on the remote machine?

Comment: Yes; you need to install the public key on the remote server (eg in `$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys`, but the SA _can_ change the location).  This Ubuntu help can provide guidance; https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys

Comment: ok! And does it let me marge also `scp`?

Comment: You don't need to merge `scp` if you use public keys and `ssh-agent`.  The authentication is automatic so you can run 10 `ssh` or `scp` commands and it won't keep re-asking for the password :-)

Comment: yeah, obviously. Pretty cool! : )

Answer (score 3):

Open an SSH connection once, and then piggyback on it. This feature of OpenSSH is called master connections. See [Using an already established SSH channel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33557/using-an-already-established-ssh-channel/33581#33581)

```
ssh_control_socket="$(mktemp)"
ssh -o ControlPath="$(ssh_control_socket)" -o ControlMaster=yes -o ControlPersist=yes administrator@host "mkdir ${DIR}"
# other commands using ssh (ssh, scp, rsync, …): pass the same ControlPath option
ssh -o ControlPath="$(ssh_control_socket)" -t administrator@host "…"
rsync -e "ssh -o 'ControlPath=$(ssh_control_socket)'" …
ssh -o ControlPath="$(ssh_control_socket)" administrator@host -O exit
rm -f "$(ssh_control_socket)"
```

Annoyingly, you need to explicitly pass a `ControlPath` option on every SSH invocation (it's the name of a file that's used to communicate between each `ssh` invocation and the original SSH client that made the actual connection). Here I pass an explicit socket name so that the script is self-contained. If relying on `~/.ssh/config` is acceptable, then add this line to your `~/.ssh/config`:

```
ControlPath ~/.ssh/%l_%h_%p_%r.multiplex
```

This makes every SSH client able to check whether there is an existing connection to piggyback on. The feature won't actually be used unless there is a listening master connection, you still need to pass `-o ControlMaster=yes` (or `-M` for short) on the first connection, i.e. your script can be

```
# Open the shared connection
ssh -M -o ControlPersist=yes administrator@host :
# … all SSH-relying commands in their basic form, they will go via the shared connection …
# Close the shared connection
ssh -O exit administrator@host
```

Comment: Host key verification failed.
No ControlPath specified for "-O" command

Comment: @superciccio14 Ah, I mistakenly thought that this was no longer necessary but it seems that it is. You need to have a `ControlPath` option to use the master connection feature, either on the command line or in the configuration file. Sorry.