# using scp renaming all files

Tags: shell-script, rename, scp

I am sending files from one server to another using scp . I need to rename files after sending that .So I use following command for each file

```
scp original-hc.db user@host:/dir/original-hc_1.db
```

I want to send all files using a single command with renaming files . Like

```
scp *.db user@host:/dir/(actual file name before extension)_1.db
```

Comment: I don't believe what you're asking for is possible in a single command. As I understand it `scp` or any copy command for that matter will allow multiple files to copy but requires a single destination and does not allow for renaming unless you are only copying a single file. There are commands to rename lots of files at once, e.g. `rename` but not one command that combines both.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can easily be achieved with a loop

```
for f in *.db
do
    scp "$f" user@host:/dir/"${f%.db}"_1.db
done
```

The `${f%.db}` construct strips off the `.db` suffix from `$f`.

Answer (score 4):

`scp` can't rename files when copying multiple files to a directory, so you'll need to use some other tool in addition or instead to perform the pattern-based renaming.

If you have SFTP access and not just SCP access, then you can use [SSHFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS) to make the remote files appear on your local machine. This allows you to use any file copy-and-renaming tool.

```
mkdir mnt
sshfs user@host:/dir
pax -rw -pe -s'/\.db$/_1.db/' *.db mnt
fusermount -u mnt
```

Instead of `pax` (which is POSIX but sometimes not installed by default on Linux though it's always available as a package), you might use GNU or BSD tar, zsh's `zcp`, etc. Or just a loop that does the copy:

```
for x in *.db; do
  cp -p "$x" "mnt/${x%.db}_1.db"
done
```

You can use the loop method even if you don't have SSHFS, but then you have to use `scp` in the loop.

```
for x in *.db; do
  scp -p "$x" "user@host:/dir/${x%.db}_1.db"
done
```

Setting up an SSH connection for each time can be a little slow. With OpenSSH, you can open the connection once and then piggyback on it. See [Using an already established SSH channel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33557/using-an-already-established-ssh-channel/33581#33581)

Another method (requiring full shell access on the server) is to archive the files and copy the archive, and apply a renaming step when archiving or when extracting. For example, if you have GNU tar locally (which is always the case on non-embedded Linux and often available, perhaps as `gtar`, on other unix variants):

```
tar -cf - --transform '/\.db$/_1.db/ *.db | ssh user@host 'cd /dir && tar -xf -'
```

With BSD tar, replace `--transform` by `-s`. If you have a very limited tar locally but GNU tar or BSD tar on the server, you can do the renaming on the server side instead.

You might want to insert a step of compression if the network bandwidth is the bottleneck. With the archive method, you can insert steps in the pipeline:

```
tar -czf - --transform '/\.db$/_1.db/ *.db | ssh user@host 'cd /dir && gunzip | tar -xf -'
```

Or you can do the compression at the SSH level, by passing the `-C` option to `ssh`, `sshfs` or `scp`.

Comment: I've just tested and scp DOES rename the file. scp src $name@$ip:/dst creates a `dst` file on the remote.

Comment: @Pi `scp` can copy one file to another file with a different name. It can't apply a renaming rule, which is what the question was about. I can see how the sentence was confusing out of context, so I've clarified it.