# Replace mutiple files with different names using scp

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

I have created a script to transfer the files generated on source server to target server but I want to replace the files on the go while transferring the file from source to target.
Please help me in achieving this.

File Name:

```
Source file names:
-------------------
EXPORT_TABLE_TEST_27-Aug-2020_02.dmp
EXPORT_TABLE_TEST_27-Aug-2020_01.dmp
```

I want to achieve something like this and the Service name(TEST,UAT) and dates  will keep differing on different server.
Please help me, it will be deeply appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

```
Target Files:
------------------
EXPORT_TABLE_UAT_28-Aug-2020_02.dmp
EXPORT_TABLE_UAT_28-Aug-2020_01.dmp
```

Code Used.

```
        if [ ! -d "${LOC1}" ]; then
                echo
                echo -e "\033[32;5mERROR: THE PROVIDED LOCATION IS NOT EXIST !\033[0m"
                echo
                echo "Please Enter the location where your EXPORTED FILES [DUMPFILES] are saved: [ENTER THE FULL DIRECTORY PATH]"
                echo "==========================================================================="
        else
                 echo
        for FILES in `find $LOC1 -type f -ctime -1`
                do
                                echo "List of  Files generated for last 24 HRS is $FILES"
                                echo ""
                                echo "=========================================================================================================="
                                echo " Transferring this Files from "$HOSTNAME" to "$DEST_SERVER" server. "
                                echo "=========================================================================================================="
                                echo ""
                               sshpass -e scp $FILES $USER@$DEST_SERVER:/$DEST_DIR/

                done
                                echo ""
                                echo "Transfer of files completed."
                break
         fi

done
```

Comment: as for me you will have to copy every file separatelly and replace names (TEST,UAT) and dates before using `scp`

Comment: see [using scp renaming all files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/307022/using-scp-renaming-all-files) - especially [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/307022/using-scp-renaming-all-files#comment539661_307022) under question.