# Rsync all directories that contain a specific file

Tags: rsync, backup

I am working on a cluster that requires both public key and password, I have a complex file structure to organize my work on this cluster, and I would like to have a backup on my local machine of some directories only.

I would like rsync to get only directories that have a file named "backup". Example:

```
data/sub1/sub1_1/backup < back up this directory
data/sub1/sub1_2/ < don't back up
```

Because of this password thing, I would like to avoid any script that calls ssh multiple times, is there any advanced filter able to do that with rsync?

Comment: Open an SSH connection the first time and keep it open. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33557/using-an-already-established-ssh-channel for how to set this up (make sure you do keep one connection open, e.g. with `ControlPersist`). That way it doesn't matter if you invoke rsync multiple times: they'll reuse the existing SSH connection.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of directories to backup is not too big, you can put them into the command line using a bash shellscript. The following shellscript is a demo.

#### Directory structure

```
$ tree data
data
└── sub1
    ├── sub1_1
    │   ├── a
    │   ├── b
    │   └── backup
    ├── sub1_2
    │   └── c
    └── sub1_3
        ├── backup
        └── d

4 directories, 6 files
```

#### Shellscript `rsyncer`

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n 'rsync -avn ' > command
find . -name 'backup' -type f | sed -e 's%/backup%%' -e 's%.*%"&"%' | tr '\n' ' ' >> command
echo ' target/' >> command

bash command
```

#### Dry run

```
$ ./rsyncer 
sending incremental file list
created directory target
sub1_1/
sub1_1/a
sub1_1/b
sub1_1/backup
sub1_3/
sub1_3/backup
sub1_3/d

sent 199 bytes  received 64 bytes  526.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00 (DRY RUN)
```

Please notice that sub1/sub1_**2** and the file **c** are not listed.

#### Backup

Remove the option `n` from rsync in the shellscript and run it or from the file `command` and run it,

```
sed 's/-avn/-av/' command > buper

$ bash buper
sending incremental file list
created directory target
sub1_1/
sub1_1/a
sub1_1/b
sub1_1/backup
sub1_3/
sub1_3/backup
sub1_3/d

sent 383 bytes  received 148 bytes  1,062.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00

$ tree target
target
├── sub1_1
│   ├── a
│   ├── b
│   └── backup
└── sub1_3
    ├── backup
    └── d

2 directories, 5 files
```

Please notice that sub1/sub1_**2** and the file **c** are not listed.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could use something like it.

1. Use the `find` command to find files that you are interested in.
2. Put them through `dirname` to print the directory name in which the file is stored.
3. Use `uniq` so the directory is listed only ones
4. Iterate over the result in rsync or put them together so rsync will be invoked only once.

Simple script:

```bsh
for i in $(find . -name 'backup' -type f | xargs dirname | uniq); do
  echo "here: $i"
  # here goes rsync
done
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but if I do that I will need to type my password each time I call rsync